# Enumerating actions for Q-learning

Tags: finance, q-learning

I have a Q-learning model that is for forex trading, so my initial thought is that there will be only 3 kinds of possible moves:

1. Buy
2. Sell
3. Hold

However, the reward for each action is different given the portfolio's holding position or market situation. For example, if we have a up trend and a buy position then we earn a reward; but if we hold a buy position in a down trend then we receive a penalty.

I wonder if I have to split the actions into subdivided actions, like:

1. Buy - Up trend
2. Buy - Down trend
3. ...

Are there any strategies or techniques that can help me derive the best set of actions to model my environment?

Answer (score 1):

The actions the agent takes are still the same: buy, sell, hold. That's all you can do.

I don't think there is any need for augmentation of the action space. You can e.g. take that all into account for the reward. Make it less if you hold a buy position in a down trend and higher. This will have the behavior emerge in a natural way, if you train it properly.

So you should rather adapt the reward function to shape the agent in a way you want it to be.